# How to know which message converter is used by spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

For some reason I decided to change to another `message converter`, my code is below

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
    HttpMessageConverter<?> additional = new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();
    return new HttpMessageConverters(additional);
}
```

Now I'd like to know how to check whether this custom converter is in effect? I tried to access `/beans` but only got this

```
{
    bean: "customConverters",
    scope: "singleton",
    type: "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters",
    resource: "com.foo.BarApplication",
    dependencies: [ ]
}
```

So does exist some manner to know which message converter is used by spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only injected dependencies are shown in the `dependencies` array. If you do something like

```
@Bean
public FastJsonHttpMessageConverter fastJsonHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HttpMessageConverters convertersToBeUsed(FastJsonHttpMessageConverter converter) {
    return new HttpMessageConverters(converter);
}
```

you will see the `FastJsonHttpMessageConverter` in the list.

If you want to see all registered converters, look for `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` in the bean list. It should look similar to this:

```
{
   bean: "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration",
   scope: "singleton",
   type: "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e15b021",
   resource: "null",
   dependencies: [
       "fastJsonHttpMessageConverter",
       "stringHttpMessageConverter"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  but when look for `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` I only got this `dependencies: [
"stringHttpMessageConverter",
"mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
]
`

Comment: If you add the two bean definitions from the answer and fastjson library is on the classpath you will see the `fastJsonHttpMessageConverter` on the list - this is how converters in spring boot work :)

Comment: Thanks! So as you said I let `FastJsonHttpMessageConverter` to be a spring managed bean, and this time when look for `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration`, got `dependencies: [
"fastJsonHttpMessageConverter",
"stringHttpMessageConverter",
"mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
]`, so I know my custom converter is the first converter.

Comment: but If I directly new an instance of `FastJsonHttpMessageConverter`, in this case I'm not very sure if this custom converter has worked or SB still uses `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to generate json body

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm not very sure if my custom converter works, so I have to track source code. I cloned spring framework then attached it in eclipse, then debug step by step and found something. 
In `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters`

```
for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : this.messageConverters)
```

when watch `this.messageConverters` got below output

```
[org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1eb0d2e8, com.alibaba.fastjson.support.spring.FastJsonHttpMessageConverter@2026476b, org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@3287cbc7, org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@2c19dd3, org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter@1afe28f1, org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter@87129da, org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@4a412e0, org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@a8528a2, org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter@61d720a3]
```

and actually it used `com.alibaba.fastjson.support.spring.FastJsonHttpMessageConverter@2026476b`

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit on how to debug step by step? In Intellij idea, I could only set a break point on the post mapped method, but that's after the converting step.  I mean, with all those annotation, and http-nio starting a new thread(so you can't set a break point on main function) for each incoming requests. It's hard to known how to set a break point to follow the request serving step by step.

Comment: @SamChan My solution is you could make some error explicitly , e.g. invalid json body, duplicate request mapping, not exists value expression, from the stack trace you could find where you should set breakpoint